# Compiling single package under winros

Tags: ros, compile, package, winros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I have successfully installed winros on my Win7 system and need to create my own Messagetype. This worked very well by createing a CMakeLists.txt in the directory and adding these two lines.

```
add_message_files(DIRECTORY msg FILES message.msg)
generate_messages()
```

I tried to compile the package with cmake but that didn't work. I got stucked with an error about the message_generationConfig.cmake which I found under C:\opt\ros\groovy\x86\share\message_generation\cmake. The commandline output advised me to add that path to an environment variable like message_generation_DIR but that haven't worked.
Well, I finally compiled all packages and my own with the messagetypes again with  "winros_make" and then the Headerfile was generated.

Has anybody figured out how to compile one single package with cmake or has somebody used the rosmake component under winros?

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64640/compiling-single-package-under-winros/) by [ChrisEule](https://answers.ros.org/users/2782/chriseule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The winros_make command just makes a call out to cmake, but potentially passes alot of variables. You can see part of winros_make's scripting which makes the call [here](https://github.com/ros-windows/win_ros/blob/groovy-devel/rosdeps/win_python_build_tools/src/win_ros/cmake.py).

You should also see the output for the cmake command that winros_make executed directly on standard output (check the print lines in the script above). At any rate, that should give you an idea of what magic winros_make is doing under the hood.

Note that rosmake is legacy - it is the tool that was used for the old build system. winros_make is effectively the windows counterpart of catkin_make on linux. It just adds a few extra windows specific features to make it easier for the user.

We plan to perhaps have a script to simplify building of packages only. I did that with fuerte - just haven't gotten that far with groovy yet.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0